# testing a single CTE in dbt

Tags: dbt

can you test a single CTE as opposed to a model?
For example, in:

```sql
# models/mymodel.sql

with my_cte as (
  {%- set tables = dbt_utils.get_relations_by_pattern('my_schema%', 'prefix%') -%}
  {%- set my_columns = ['my_col1', 'mycol2', 'mycol3',...,]
  {{ dbt_utils.union_relations(relations = tables, include=my_columns ) }}
),

clean_cols as (
  select 
    my_col1::numeric as mycol1,
    coalesce(mycol2, mycol3) as my_coalesced_col23,
    ....
  from my_cte
)

select * from clean_cols
```

I’d want to test that mycol2 and mycol3 are mutually exclusive (I have a custom generic test)

NOTE: I need those things to stay in the same file, otherwise it becomes very difficult to manage correctness with a long list of columns. Having the columns to `include` and `select` all in one place follows the best practice of [rename and recast fields once](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/guides/best-practices#rename-and-recast-fields-once) and in one place.

Comment: p.s. what database are you using?

Comment: using postrgres

Answer (score 2):

In your current implementation, the answer is no. However, if you use the [ephemeral materialization](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/building-models/materializations#ephemeral), it totally is possible! In this case you break your first CTE into it's own `.sql` model, then configure it like below. In this way you can test the `unioner.sql` model, but when you invoke `dbt run`, there will not be a `unioner` model, the logic instead gets injected into the `my_cte` definition in `my_model` instead.

```sql
-- models/unioner.sql
{{
  config(
    materialized = 'ephemeral',
    )
}}
{%- set tables = dbt_utils.get_relations_by_pattern('my_schema%', 'prefix%') -%}
{{ dbt_utils.union_relations(relations = tables ) }}
```

```sql
-- models/mymodel.sql

with my_cte as (
  SELECT * FROM {{ ref('unioner') }}
),

clean_cols as (
  select 
    my_col1,
    coalesce(mycol2, mycol3)
    ....
  from my_cte
)

select * from clean_cols
```

Comment: Thanks, @Anders Swanson, but I really need those things to stay in the same file. Updated original question as to why